# Using Loop function with arcpy.Exists()?

Tags: python, arcpy

I have a code snippet using elif that checks if a file exists and continues to check through the letters of the alphabet (for example _A, _B, _C etc). All works fine but I think there must a better (or cleaner) way to write the code using a loop function instead of the way I have done.

```
#Create MXD file path
mxdOutput = wrFolder + "/M_" + WorkrequestRaw +"_01.mxd"
mxdPath = wrFolder + "/M_" + WorkrequestRaw +"_01"

#check for latest version and create next letter
if  not arcpy.Exists(mxdOutput):
    mxdOutput = wrFolder + "/M_" + WorkrequestRaw +"_01.mxd"
    pdfversion = ""
elif not arcpy.Exists(mxdPath +"_A.mxd"):
    mxdOutput = wrFolder + "/M_" + WorkrequestRaw +"_01_A.mxd"
    pdfversion = "A"
elif not arcpy.Exists(mxdPath +"_B.mxd"):
    mxdOutput = wrFolder + "/M_" + WorkrequestRaw +"_01_B.mxd"
    pdfversion = "B"
elif not arcpy.Exists(mxdPath +"_C.mxd"):
    mxdOutput = wrFolder + "/M_" + WorkrequestRaw +"_01_C.mxd"
    pdfversion = "C"
elif not arcpy.Exists(mxdPath +"_D.mxd"):
    mxdOutput = wrFolder + "/M_" + WorkrequestRaw +"_01_D.mxd"
    pdfversion = "D"
```

I am a self taught beginner and trying to keep the code tidy. Welcome any comments on a better methodology?

Update poorly written question: What I am trying to do is if file name exists write new file called 'filenameA' and if 'filenameA' exists write 'filenameB' and if 'filenameB exists write 'filenameC' etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
names = ['','_A', '_B', '_C']

mxdPath = wrFolder + "/M_" + WorkrequestRaw +"_01"

for name in names:
  mxdOutput = mxdPath + name + '.mxd'
  if not arcpy.Exists(mxdOutput):
      pdfversion = name
      break
```

Comment: nice job with putting '' in the list of names, hadn't thought of that.

Comment: So what happens if A and B exist? In this code B trumps A.. that is probably the most likely situation. Mac, if you want to stop at A (or the earliest version that exists) you can include a *break* statement to stop the iteration. Nice solution Nathan, concise and simple.

Comment: Thanks @Nathan W. I substituted the code and it wrote 'filenameC' first (instead of just 'filename', and then on the second iteration did nothing. I have edited my question to make it clearer

Comment: Are you sure?  It works for me here. http://i.imgur.com/qIwzn4r.png

Comment: I get the error "'break' outside loop" when using 'break'. I comment out the break and runs but loops through to the last letter. In @Luke example does same and ends up at Z. I guess I am not understanding 'break' being used  with if statement?

Comment: Well if you get that error you code isn't nested right.  I suspect you don't have the `if` inside the `for`

Comment: Duh....note to self - respect indentations. Works fine once I indented correctly. Thanks for your assistance

Answer (score 3):

This question is pretty close to off-topic (pure python). However, here is another method.

```
import os, sys, string
import arcpy

mxdPath = os.path.join(wrFolder, "M_" + WorkrequestRaw +"_01")

for letter in [''] + list(string.ascii_uppercase):
    mxdOutput = (mxdPath + '_' + letter).strip('_')+ '.mxd'
    if not arcpy.Exists(mxdOutput):
        pdfversion = name
        break
    if letter=='Z':
        raise RuntimeError('No more backup filenames available!')
```

Comment: Good use of ascii_uppercase as a list, +1 for that. Doesn't account for '' though. Perhaps chars = [''].extend(string.ascii_uppercase) then for letter in chars.

Comment: Didn't even know about `ascii_uppercase`.  Nifty.

Comment: This worked as well but as @Michael points out I need to check for '' first.

Answer (score 3):

I strongly recommend using os.path.exists() when checking the existence of files (especially inside a loop)! The arcpy.Exists() function is slow and it is much faster to use os.path.exists().

Answer (score 1):

Try this to construct name:

```
for i in range(10):
    fName='%s_%s.mxd'%("BASENAME",chr(65+i))
```

and break if does not exist. Construct new name using i

Comment: That's a great method if letters go beyond C, that way you can go from A to Z and with a little more work with divide and mod you can do AA to ZZ. Doesn't account for '' though.